# Change Label content via using DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use the following code to change label text using animation:

```
DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
SplineDoubleKeyFrame Spline = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00")));
Animation.KeyFrames.Add(Spline);
Spline = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(100, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01.4000000")), new KeySpline(0, 0.284, 0.39, 1));
Animation.KeyFrames.Add(Spline);
sRank.BeginAnimation(Label.ContentProperty, Animation);
```

but its show me this error:

> Cannot animate the 'Content' property on a
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Label' using a
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames'.

I think it can't convert double value to string. so what is your solution to do this?

Comment: Errr... maybe the [`StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stringanimationusingkeyframes(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: The linked question is NOT a dupe, because it can be answered with Keyframes, whereas this Q can not.

Comment: `DoubleAnimation` documentation says: "Animates the value of a Double property...". `Content` is not a Double property.